# Property View isn't updated after property selection change

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I am trying to select another *EditPart* programatically and it works so long.
But the corresponding view isn't updated.

With the debugger I found out, that the system gets the right property object, but the values and so on aren't shown in the property view.
I use the `selectionChanged` method from the *UndoablePropertySheetPage*.

```
propertyPage.selectionChanged(this, new StructuredSelection(editPart));
```

Thanks for any advices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is very simple, you can use the method `refresh` provided by *UndoablePropertySheetPage*, after selection of the element in the viewer.